# Field separators

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a lot of programming experience, but I am fairly new to awk.  Something is not behaving as I expect.  Can somebody put me straight?

On linux, my command:
gawk -f do3 tmp6.txt

My source file do3

```
#!/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
FS="-"
}
{print "Two is " $2 "One is" $1 "zero is" $0}
```

My input file, tmp6.txt

```
~BAND:3-10M
~MODE:2-CW
~QSO_DATE:8-20111130
~TIME_ON:6-175415
~eor-

~PFX:2-K4
~CQZ:1-5
~ITUZ:1-8
~eor-
```

My output to the console:

```
One is~BAND:3zero is~BAND:3-10M
One is~MODE:2zero is~MODE:2-CW
One is~QSO_DATE:8zero is~QSO_DATE:8-20111130
One is~TIME_ON:6zero is~TIME_ON:6-175415
One is~eorzero is~eor-
zero isOne is
One is~PFX:2zero is~PFX:2-K4  
One is~CQZ:1zero is~CQZ:1-5
One is~ITUZ:1zero is~ITUZ:1-8
One is~eorzero is~eor-
zero isOne is
```

Taking the first line as the example, what I could have expected was
in every line, what I think should be the beginning would be

```
Two is followed by the value assigned to $2, the value after the "-" in each line.
```

However, that is missing in every case.

Other cases that are more complex exhibit even more unusual behavior (like back-tabbing), but if I can figure this part out, maybe that will help me understand the rest.

Thanks in advance,
JimR

Comment: works for me http://ideone.com/Twgd4V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your file seems to contain ^M at the end of the line. Before running the `gawk` command:

```
dos2unix tmp6.txt
```

which will remove the ^M characters.

Comment: Spot on, thanks.  You can't imagine how many hours I have pored over this, trying to simplify it.  Of course, the ^M do NOT show up in vi.  As soon as you mentioned this, I tried the mcedit built into Midnight Commander, and sure enough, there they were!  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @JimR: If you mean doesn't show up in vim, that is intentional. See [this tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip736) on how to get a warning when opening non-native file formats.

Comment: @JimR: Another way to deal with line-endings is by telling gawk about them: `BEGIN { RS = ORS = "\r\n" } ...` if you want to preserve dos line-endings or `BEGIN { RS = "\r\n" }` to output native line-endings.